# Put the code from a FORM in a .cpp file

Tags: forms, file, c++-cx

I have a form created in this way (the .h file of form is named `Example`):

This is a default code from a form:

```
namespace ExampleNamespace{

public ref class Example : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
   public:
        void DoSomething()
        {
              // code here
        }
};
}
```

I can to this ?

Creating a new .cpp file and named `Example.cpp` am put here all the code from the form in .cpp ? In this way don't work.

```
namespace ExampleNamespace{

public ref class Example : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
   public:
        void DoSomething(); //if i try in this way I will have the error from above
};
}
```

and in `Example.cpp`

```
#include "Example.h"

void Example::DoSomething()
{
   //code here
}
```

If I try to add `public: void DoSomething();` in form i have this error:

```
error LNK2020: unresolved token (060000BB) ExampleNamespace.Example::DoSomething
```

Comment: what is your question? what have you tried? When you say "don't work", you need to be more specific (error messages, compiler output, ...) if you expect proper help

Comment: That isn't C++ code, it's [C++/CX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CX).

Comment: I bet the compiler doesn't say, "don't work".  I bet the compiler gives a helpful error message. You can see that message, but we cannot. Please remedy that flaw in your question.,

Comment: The first code is a default code of a new form application. The question is if I can put all the code from every method in a .cpp file. The secound code is a way how I try to do, but don't work.

Comment: All your examples say DoSomething with an uppercase D

The compiler say ExampleNamespace.Example::doSomething with a lowercase d

Comment: @AnDr3yy you see, the compiler says it can't find `ExampleNamespace.Example::doSomething` because you defined `Example::DoSomething` without the namespace `ExampleNamespace` in your *.cpp file. Then, as Mare Infinitus mentioned, you also have problems matching the case.

Comment: @MareInfinitus somebody edited my code and put D instade of d how it was at first.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, you need to include the namespace after include the .h file like this in the .cpp file:

```
#include "Example.h"

using namespace ExampleNamespace;
```

And in *.h file you need to put this code:

```
#ifndef _EXAMPLE_H_
#define _EXAMPLE_H_
```

and

```
#endif
```

like this:

```
#ifndef _EXAMPLE_H_
#define _EXAMPLE_H_

namespace ExampleNamespace{

public ref class Example : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
   public:
        void DoSomething()
        {
              // code here
        }
};
}

#endif
```